# Content of string array is same on all positions - i need asistance

Tags: c

im working on my project to school and i run on this issue and cant continue forward. Can you plese help me? Im geting data from text document and and trying it save line by line to string array. When i printf data to stdin they are shown how they shuld be, but when i try it to printf them out of while function, conecent of all positions in array is last line of text document.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
    //Validate command line arguments 
    if (argc != 2) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE : %s file.txt\n", argv[0]); 
        return(1); 
    } 
     
    //Open text file for reading 
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
 
    //Error exit if there was a problem opening the above file 
    if (f == NULL) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s \n", argv[1]); 
        return(1); 
    } 

    int i = 0;
    char *array[1000];
    char line[500];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {

        array[i]=line;
        printf("%d",i);
        printf("%s", array[i]);
        i++; 
    }
    printf("%s", array[1]);
    printf("%s", array[2]);
    printf("%s", array[3]);
    printf("%s", array[4]);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

- 0U 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
- 1S a b c x
- 2S    x y z
- 3C intersect 2 3
- 4C minus 2 3C minus 2 3C minus 2 3C    minus 2 3

Thnx guys <3

Comment: You have a single `line` that all the pointers you store in `array` point to. You need to store this differently (e.g.: make `char array[1000][500]` and read directly into that)

Comment: thnx, i got it. I can now move on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for *each* line you read.  Currently you only have the one `line[]`. For example, change the line

```
array[i]=line;
```

to

```
array[i]=(char *)malloc(strlen(line)+1);
strcpy(array[i], line);
```

This will make allocate space for each string, and copy your line to it.